# relational database and oop javascript

Tags: javascript, relational-database

i am trying to create a relational database while using oop in java script , yet i am encountered with some difficulties , this is the code ,
IT WAS WORKING BEFORE I CHANGED IT TO OOP

```
function DB() {
this.size;
this.row;

this.getsize = function() {
    return this.size;
}

this.db = window.openDatabase('coupons', "1.0", 'database for coupons', 100000);
this.al = function() {
    alert('al works');
}
this.add = function(table, id, name, email, fav) {
    // alert("works");
    // alert("INSERT INTO " + table + " VALUES(" + id + "," + name + ")");
    this.db.transaction(function(ob)
    {
        ob.executeSql("SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE pid= " + id + "", [], this.dataHandler, this.errorHandler);

    });
    this.db.transaction(function(ob)
    {
        //alert(getsize());
        if (this.size > 0) {
            alert("user already exists")
        } else {
            ob.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + table + " (pid INTEGER, pname TEXT, pemail TEXT,pfav)");
            ob.executeSql("INSERT INTO " + table + " VALUES(" + id + "," + "'" + name + "'" + "," + "'" + email + "'" + "," + "'" + fav + "'" + ")");
            alert("user addd successfuly");
        }
    }
    );
}
this.errorHandler = function(error)
{
    document.write("handling error " + error);
}
this.dataHandler = function(transaction, data)
{
    // document.write("<table>");
    //document.write("<tr><th>id</th><th>name</th></tr>")
    // size = data.rows.length;
    //for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    //   {

    //Variables.call(this,data.rows.length,data.rows.item(0));
    //Variables.call(7,6);

    this.size = data.rows.length;
    this.row = data.rows.item(0);






    //return row;
    //       document.write(
    //      "<tr><td>"+row['pid']+"</td><td>"+row['pname']+"</td></tr>");
    //   }
    //document.write("</table>");
}

this.getrows = function(n)
{
    switch (n)
    {
        case 'pid':
            return this.row['pid'];
            break;
        case 'pname':
            return this.row['pname'];
            break;
        case 'pemail':
            return this.row['pemail'];
            break;
        case 'pfav':
            return this.row['pfav'];
            break;
        default:
    }
}
```

}

the problem are as follows , hope you can help me out !! 
1.after calling the function add , it does not go to dataHandler function .
2. in the add function i am unable to use local variables , how can i use the variable 'size' to check if the user exists in the database or not  ?!!  ,
hope you can help i have been in this code for 2 days !!! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You obviously can't access this.size in your function because you are using a anonymous function, so this is not related to your DB -oject but points to that anonymous function.
The same for your calls to this.dataHandler or this.errorHandler.
So you could just

```
this.db.transaction = function(ob)
```

to make it a method of your object which then will give you full access to the this - pointer of your DB - Object.
EDIT: Sorry, this would then point to the db  object, of course, so this is not a solution.
But you can pass it your data - and errorHandler like this:

```
this.db.transaction(function() { ... }, this.errorHandler, this.dataHandler);
```

and avoid the call to this.size within the second transaction - statement by simply wrapping your call like:

```
 if(this.size > 0) { alert('..'); } else { db.transaction(...) }
```

But: Your errorHandler and dataHandler must actually correspond to the right interface - definitions, take a look at:
http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090212/structured-client-side-storage.html

Comment: thx man !! now every thing is clear :) i took by your advice and  it works fine :)